# Loading a partial (external) html page using colorbox jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, colorbox

How do i get it to use only a containing div inside a linked html page.? Loading complete page is fine. However i wish to load only a child div of the loaded page.

html

```
<a href="/OrchardLocal/FactFindPreview?id=5" class="cboxElement">View Fact Submission</a>
```

jquery (on doc ready)

```
$(".required-info a").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "80%", height: "80%" });
```

Comment: ehm, length of the question's title is more than question's body.

Comment: Add your code in the question body... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ColorBox's ajax functionality is handled by jQuery's load() method, so it works the same way.  The URL you pass to colorbox with have to be suffixed with a space, then a selector for the content you want to display.  For example: `$.colorbox({href: "mypage.html #myselector"});`

Your usage would look something like this:

```
$(".required-info a").colorbox({ href: function(){ return $(this).attr('href') + ' #mycontainer'; }, width: "80%", height: "80%" });
```